# Maven release plugin and using a single version in the parent pom

Tags: maven, version, multi-module, parent-pom

I have a multi-module maven project.
I hold the version in one location in the parent pom.xml as a property
and then use this in the **parent** pom.xml:

```
<project>
   <artifactId>autoav</artifactId>
   <version>${autoAvVersion}</version>      
...
   <properties>
        <autoAvVersion>19.3.24-SNAPSHOT</autoAvVersion>
   </properties>
</project>
```

And use this in the **child** module :

```
<project>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.analysis</groupId>
  <version>${autoAvVersion}</version>
  <artifactId>analysisCore</artifactId>
  <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.analysis</groupId>
        <version>${autoAvVersion}</version>
        <artifactId>autoav</artifactId>
        <relativePath>../autoAV</relativePath>
  </parent>
...
</project>
```

Maven release plugin, after running prepare+perform on the child project only (just for testing one module), changed my child pom version from

```
<version>${autoAvVersion}</version>
```

to

```
<version>19.3.25-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

So i suppose the release plugin did not think of cases using a single point version.
(By the way if i omit the version tag in the child, so it effectively gets it from the parent, the version tag without the property [19.3.25-SNAPSHOT] is still added to the child

Is there any solution to this ?

Comment: I had the same problem and found no solution. I went back to adding the version to every module (without properties).

Comment: If your parent has a version adding a supplemental version is not needed cause it's inherited.

Comment: @JFMeier - i decided to stop using release plugin as i found a bug that when i perform release:prepare on a parent pom, the git tag phase would fail on the last child because it would cut off the git scm repository url after the last slash just when trying to tag ( i has something like <scm> <connection>scm:git:git@hub.mycompany.com:company-infra/analysis.git</connection> and only in the last tag operation it would try to tag using 'git@hub.mycompany.com:company-infra/' without the 'analysis.git' in the end)
 </scm>

Comment: @khmarbaise I mean that I explicitly specify the parent version in each module instead of using something like ´${revision}` because `${revision}` does not work with Maven release plugin.